# Bootstrap row padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3 I'm aware that if a row does not sit inside its container you get extra space due to the -15px of margin either side, compensating for the container, which has a gutter.

I thought this could solve the problem:

```
.row{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

.container .row{
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-right:-15px;
}
```

But for some reason the margin persists so you get a slight horizontal scroll on mobile devices, which ruins the overall appeal.

(If it helps I could give the address of the site I'm working on?)

Comment: Can you show a fiddle for this?

Comment: padding or margin?

Comment: That horizontal scroll is being caused by one of the elements on your site overflowing the grid. That is the only time this happens in Bootstrap. You need to figure out which element it is - and then either add overflow:hidden to the parent, or fix that elements width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .container-fluid

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-XX-XX"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think that you're using .row without any .col-XX-XX inside. That may cause the problem.